# How to update fields based on newest date - Google BigQuery / SQL

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

how are you doing?

I have a table with media results (facebook, instagram, linkedin, etc) in Google BigQuery.
One of the columns is the ad image link, but my database is daily and the link expires after a certain time.

**I need to replace all links with the most recent one, but I have some conditions for this:**

**The link must be the most recent (based on the 'date' column) within the combination of platform and ad_id columns.**

That is, if an AD ran for 10 days, it will have 10 different links, but I need it to become just ONE link replicated 10 times (the most recent link).

I have already written a part of the code, **which returns me only the most recent links within this condition:**

```
SELECT as value ARRAY_AGG(media ORDER BY date DESC LIMIT 1)[OFFSET(0)]
FROM `project.dataset.media` media
GROUP BY platform, ad_id, ad_img_link
```

I'm just not getting the final part, which needs to update all the values (within these conditions) replacing the values that are inside this query.

I really appreciate the help.

Answer (score 1):

I think you need to use [window functions](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/window-function-calls), because they keep the original number of rows in your table, while aggregating over partitions.

```
SELECT LAST_VALUE(ad_img_link) OVER(
    PARTITION BY platform, ad_id 
    ORDER BY date ASC 
    RANGE BETWEEN UNBOUNDED PRECEDING AND UNBOUNDED FOLLOWING
) AS ad_most_recent_img_link
FROM `project.dataset.media` media
```

The LAST_VALUE() function takes the last value of the partition and inserts it into all rows of the partition. The last value is defined by the ORDER BY column and the window (in this case the window is always the entire partition).

Comment: yeah, it makes sense! And how can I update my table using query schedule now?

UPDATE table.name
SET ad_most_recent_img_link = ??